# Salvar dados do ClientDataSet em um arquivo XML

Tags: delphi

Fiz um sistema de cadastro simples sem envolver banco de dados, preciso saber como eu gravo arquivos do cadastro do ClientDataSet em um arquivo XML e quando eu for consultar eles apareçam na minha grid!

Comment: Assim eu consegui gerar o arquivo XML- Apenas clicando em cima do ClientDataSet com o o botão direito do mouse e na opção 'Save to MyBase XML table' agora eu preciso setar para salvar nesse arquivo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para salvar o `TClientDataSet` em um arquivo xml:

```
ClientDataSet1.SaveToFile('c:\teste.xml', dfXML); //Como bem lembrado pelo @Caputo
```

Para carregar o `TClientDataSet` de um arquivo xml:

```
ClientDataSet1.LoadFromFile('c:\teste.xml');
```

Arquivo criado pelo comando SaveToFile:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só um adendo. No método save to file, recomendo utilizar o segundo parâmetro como dfBinary ou dfXML que é referente ao formato dos dados no arquivo. O padrão, se não informado é dfBinary

Comment: @Caputo +1 pela lembrança, estranho aqui ter salvo direto no exemplo.

Comment: É que o parâmetro possui um default para dfBinary. Seu exemplo está certo, além de ser a forma mais utilizada